# How to avoid heap allocation in anonymous function?

Tags: go

Here is the following example with two functions.
Anonymous function f0 however with float and string variables, for some strange reason, moves them to heap.
Any ideas how to avoid unnecessary allocations?

```
import (
    "testing"
)

var _int int32 = 10
var _float float32 = 10
var _string = "go"

var f0 = func(v interface{}) {
    _ = v
}

func f1(v interface{}) {
    _ = v
}

func Benchmark(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        f0(_int)
        f1(_int)
        f0(_float) // <- alloc
        f1(_float)
        f0(_string) // <- alloc
        f1(_string)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the parameter type of your functions is `interface{}`, an implicit interface value have to be created when values are passed to them. This interface value creation is what requires allocation.

It does not happen with `f1()` because that function will be inlined.

It also doesn't happen with `_int` because it's a "small" integer value and [Go 1.5 added optimization](https://utcc.utoronto.ca/%7Ecks/space/blog/programming/Go115InterfaceSmallInts) to wrap small integers (0 to 255) in interface values, hence not requiring allocation.

Note that if you change value of `_int` to bigger than `255`, that will also require an allocation:

```
var _int int32 = 1000 // This will also require allocation when passed to f0()
```

Comment: The provided reason is incorrect: it's not because they are variables, it's because the functions receive an interface{} argument. interface{} forces the allocation if the passed argument is not a pointer.

Comment: @CAFxX If so, values passed to `f1()` would also escape, yet they don't, even if we disable inlining.

Comment: They would but interfaces have a special mode for "small integers" that do not require allocation. If you used a bigger integer value for `_int` (>256) it would allocate. You can refer to https://utcc.utoronto.ca/~cks/space/blog/programming/Go115InterfaceSmallInts for the details.

Comment: @CAFxX What I'm saying is if using `interface{}` would be the cause for escaping, it would escape in both `f0` and `f1` cases. Yet it only escapes for `f0`. So that alone is not the cause.

Comment: Yes, let's see if this clarifies: in the case of _int it never allocates because it uses the small integer optimization mentioned above. In the case of f1, it never is because as you correctly point out it's inlined, not being a variable. You point out that even for f0 and _int it escapes, but escapes != allocation, due to the small integer optimization. If you replaced the variables with pointers, they would still escape, but nothing would get allocated.
I.e. the problem of the allocation is not f0 being a variable (albeit it plays a part), but rather passing non-pointers as interfaces.

Comment: @CAFxX Ups, I mixed escaping and allocation in my reasoning. You're right, care to post it as an answer?